# How do I take out a specific card from a deck image?

Tags: java

I want to take out a card from my deck image. How can I do that without downloading every single card separately? I don't want to initialize all 52 cards in my class.

Right now, I randomize colour and value and then it finds the picture in my source folder. But is it possible to only take one card out from my single deck image?

```
bild = ImageIO.read(new File("source folder/" + colour + value + ".png"));
```

Comment: It's hard to help without examples about what you want

Comment: The question is very unclear. Imagine that who's reading has no idea of what you're doing. Please, read these two links and then edit you question to insert more information. http://stackoverflow.com/tour and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You should read all of your card images when you start your application.  That way, all of the card images are in memory.  You can then access them as you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initialize them all but you don't have to do it by hands.

You should create one image that contains every single card and load it. `BufferedImage` class provides you a `getSubImage(int x, int y, int w, int h);` and is returning a piece (a card) of your `BufferedImage.`

You can populate an array of card while looping through the image of your deck.

```
    for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 13; j++){
            deckArray[13 * i + j] == image.getSubImage(i * cardWidth,
                                                       j * cardHeight, 
                                                       cardWidth, 
                                                       cardHeight);
        }
    }
```

Something like this. Note that I'm assuming 4*13 images os sheet and no space between them.
 You will have to find a way to track you cards, which one is which in your array no matter how you store them, because what you definietly don't want is loading an image every time you want to use it.

It's not tested and not 100% sure I did all the math corretly, just a quick reference how could you achive something like this.

Answer (score 0):

You still have to load the entire image but when you're drawing, just use

```
g.drawImage(Image img, int dstx1, int dsty1, int dstx2, int dsty2, int srcx1, int srcy1, int srcx2, int srcy2, ImageObserver observer);
```

The src (=source) values will be the upper left und lower right coordinates within your image that define the part you want to draw while the dst (=destination) values will decide where it will be drawn.